# Determining the order of a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I found this `Thread` question. The answers I feel that might be correct are, abc123 and 123abc only. How can it bring a1bc23 as a correct answer?

The said method, is a synchronized static method. So if thread letters or numbers grab the key it should access the key of the class. Once it is grabbed it won't release the key until the thread is completed. So how can an answer like a1bc23 would come? And in this case do threads access the the class thread?

```
public class ExamQ32 {
    public static synchronized void say(String s) {
        System.out.print(s);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread letters = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                say("a");
                say("b");
                say("c");
            }
        };

        Thread numbers = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                say("1");
                say("2");
                say("3");
            }
        };
        letters.start();
        numbers.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Once it is grabbed it won't release the key until the thread is completed"  Where does it say this?  Where does it hold a lock for the whole time a thread is running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The answers I feel that might be correct are, abc123 and 123abc*

Well no, Lets have a look at what you are doing.

```
public static synchronized void say(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);

}
```

The above code specifies that *only* one thread can execute this method at a time. When one thread finishes its `say()` , any other thread can execute it.

Now,

```
     Thread letters = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            say("a");
            say("b");
            say("c");
        }
    };

    Thread numbers = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            say("1");
            say("2");
            say("3");
        }
    };
```

Creates 2 threads, The important thing to be noted is `say("a")` , `say("b")` and `say("c")`  aren't guaranteed to be executed consecutively. They run in the same thread but they are not guaranteed to be executed one after another. When `say("a")` finishes, thread letters might *pause* and thread numbers might start executing. So, your output isn't guaranteed.

To get epected output, you need to lock - `ExamQ32.class` in each run method (as shown below) because your `say()` is static
Change your code to the following to get expected output :

```
public class ExamQ32 {
public static void say(String s) {
    System.out.print(s);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread letters = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (ExamQ32.class) {
                say("a");
                say("b");
                say("c");
            }
        }
    };

    Thread numbers = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            synchronized (ExamQ32.class) {
                say("1");
                say("2");
                say("3");
            }
        }
    };
    letters.start();
    numbers.start();
}
```

}

Comment: :) Oki.. Does it mean to run the say() method each thread must keep the class key until a Thread is completed?

Comment: @user3789200 - Exactly.. This blocks other thread(s) from accessing anything at the class level in `ExamQ32` class. Thus you can either have `abc123` or `123abc` depending on which thread started first.

Comment: Ok... If the say() was not static I must use public synchronized void say(String s) {} only.. It means the thread must use "this" object key . What does it mean by "this". Please kindly explain me that as well.

Comment: @user3789200 -  No. `this` represents the *current object* in the *current class*. So, in your example `synchronized(this)` will lock 2 different objects for 2 different threads. Because you are doing `new Thread { .. here this means current thread object}` . You will have to create a separate lock which is common and independent of the two threads context. - check naveejr's answer. If you use directly `synchronized (this)`, your output will still be *unpredictable*.

Comment: Oki... Then does it mean if the thread "letter" access the say() method it shold hv its's object's key to access say(). If Thread numbers would access it it would be needed its key to access it? So say() will be accessed using two keys as there are two objects. Is that correct? Sorry for troubling... I somehow need to understand clearly.... :(

Comment: @user3789200 - No. `Synchronization` works only if threads try to have Lock on the *same* object. Both `letter` and 'Number` threads should Lock on *same* object. Once one thread gets the lock, another has to wait for the lock as there is only **one lock**.

Comment: Then in this case as well both threads are trying to access the same object right? If it was not static will the case would hv been same. Hope it is yes..

Comment: @user3789200 - If the method was static, then the lock would be on the *class object* i.e, `ExamQ32.class` , So, it is fine . If `say()` wasn't static, then you have to use one object as *lock* (check naveenjr's answer) and both threads try to access `say()` using the same lock. Whichever thread gets the lock,will execute. So output can be either `abc123` or `123abc`. Synchronizing on `this` will lock on **2** objects (each thread will lock on itself), so, the output is guaranteed.

Answer (score 3):

You have different invocation of the `say` method per Thread. As you can read in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), the `synchronized` keyword specifies that that two `Threads` can't execute the method at the same time. But when the `say("a")` invocation returns, the other thread can execute.

Since `letters` is started first, it will *usually* enter the `say` method first, while `numbers` will block on `say("1")` until `say("a")` completes. After that `numbers` will continue the execution entering the `say` method (and preventing `letters` to enter it, blocking it until `numbers` exits the method).

So you will normally see interleaved letters and numbers in your output.

Comment: Hmm... I have synchronized only the say(). So that means the thread owns the methods key only until the method finishes. So in the second invocation there will be another competition to grab the key. Is it? And does static method owns "this" object key or is it the class type of a key?

Comment: Static methods hold the calss object. In This case, `ExamQ32.class`

Answer (score 2):

All the three calls to the `say()` method within a thread are not synchronized. Individual calls to the synchronized method `say()` will acquire the lock and release it as soon as the method execution is complete.

Therefore, when `Thread1-> say()` is completed execution the lock is released which can be acquired by `Thread2->say()`. 
To get the output something like `abc123` or `123abc` you need synchronization across all the three calls.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread letters = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
              synchronized(ExamQ32.class){
                say("a");
                say("b");
                say("c");
              }
            }
        };

        Thread numbers = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
              synchronized(ExamQ32.class){
                say("1");
                say("2");
                say("3");
              }
            }
        };
        letters.start();
        numbers.start();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please explain me this case as well. Why it has synchronized like this? What does it say?

Comment: Which case are you talking about?

Comment: @user3789200 - He is using `synchronize(ExamQ32,class)`. Doing this will ensure that the other thread cannot call `say()` unless the block of synchronized ends for the other. Note : He is synchronizing on the *class* because the method `say()` is static

Answer (score 2):

You call the say() separately. for each invocation it acquire  the lock and release the lock.   If you want a more predictable output modify the program as follows

```
public class ExamQ32 {

     private static Object lock = new Object();

        public static  void say(String s) {
            System.out.print(s);

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Thread letters = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
           sychronized(lock){
                    say("a");
                    say("b");
                    say("c");
                  }
                }
            };

            Thread numbers = new Thread() {
                public void run() {

            synchronized(lock){
                    say("1");
                    say("2");
                    say("3");
                    }
                }
            };
            letters.start();
            numbers.start();
        }
    }
```

It will ensure the output is either "abc123" or "123abc"